# image in cell overlaying text

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

The image seems to overlay the text in the cell, I'm not sure why this is happening but I'd like the text to go over the image. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is how my code looks like.

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 90);
    self.customImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.customImage];
    [self.customImage release];


    CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(100, 2, 198, 30);
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame];
    title.tag = 0011;
    title.numberOfLines = 2;
    title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:title];
    [title release];

}

UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0011];
title.text = [currentFeed title];

NSString *directoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *imgURL = [currentFeed thumbnailURL];
NSArray *parts = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imgURL] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *imageName = [parts objectAtIndex:[parts count]-2];

NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

UIImage  *myview = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if(myview){
    cell.imageView.image = myview;
}else{
    NSData* imageDataTemp = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[currentFeed thumbnailURL]];
    if(imageDataTemp){
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDataTemp];
    }else{
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youtubeLogo.png"];
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

[image: How the cells look like]

Answer (score 0):

`cell.imageView.image` is not your  `self.customImage` you added.Now it displayes the tableview cel default  imageview in cell

```
self.customImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.customImage];
[self.customImage setTag:12345];
[self.customImage release];
```

and get the added custom imageview as

```
UIImageView *imageVW=[cell viewWithTag:12345];
```

and use this imageview to set image later in the code instead of cell.imageview